# RequireJS on jquery bind event does not fire method

Tags: jquery, events, error-handling, binding, requirejs

Using requirejs with jquery I face a problem with method calling on binded event. Having the following code:

```js
define(["jquery"], function($) {


  function showRowItem(item) {
        console.log('method in');
       
  }
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery('ul#topnav-firstrow li').each(function () {

            jQuery(this).bind("mouseover", function (event) {
                if (outTimerID != null) {
                    clearTimeout(outTimerID);
                    outTimerID = null;
                }
                globalMouseOverItem = this;
                inTimerID = window.setTimeout("showRowItem(globalMouseOverItem)", inDelay);
            });
          
          });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

when I hover on item event is getting fired but method not recognized

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showRowItem is not defined
```

here is a codepen http://codepen.io/deroccha/pen/WxQLoy for reproducing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a string to `setTimeout` is both bad and not necessary, and doing so causes the problem you ran into because the evaluation of the string is delayed and thus happens outside the context where `showRowItem` is available. You could do this instead:

```
window.setTimeout(showRowItem.bind(globalMouseOverItem), inDelay);
```

Or with the current code you have this would be equivalent:

```
window.setTimeout(showRowItem.bind(this), inDelay);
```

and you could omit `globalMouseOverItem`.